# how do i make my android application play music from the phone's music player?

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I've created an application, and now want it to be able to connect to the `MediaPlayer` on the phone, and play the songs from there, without leaving my application.

I want to add a toggle button that, when switched on, will start playing the playlists on the phone.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
         ToggleButton tbMusic;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tbMusic=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbMusic);
        if(tbMusic.isChecked())
        {
            //here i want the command to be start playing the music
        }
        tbMusic.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.property, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(v.getId()==R.id.tbMusic)
        {
            if(tbMusic.isChecked())
            {
                //here i want the command to be start playing the music
            }
            else
            {
                //here i want a command that will stop the media player.
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Private MediaPalyer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.mymusic);

    tbMusic=(ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.tbMusic);
    if(tbMusic.isChecked())
    {
       mp.start();
    }
    tbMusic.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.property, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(v.getId()==R.id.tbMusic)
    {
        if(tbMusic.isChecked())
        {
            mp.start();
        }
        else
        {
            mp.pause();
        }
    }
}
```